# Remove state from history using react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

I'm using react-router-dom
I'm navigating from Screen A to Screen B and assigns a state `clearData`. Like below:

```
this.props.history.push({pathname: '/B', state: {clearData: true}})
```

Now when I navigate from Screen B to Screen C and come back to screen B, I want to clear state `clearData` in screen B. 
How do I achieve it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this use

```
componentWillRecieveProps(props){
if(props.location.state !==this.props.location.state && 
   props.location.state.clearData){

   this.setState(initial_state_obj)

}
```

You can also get it on componentDidMount event!

Comment: What is initial_state_obj here?

Comment: Your initial state of the component or reducer!

Comment: Can you please give me an example if possible? :)